# If element is clicked do this funciton unless this child is clicked

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

In SharePoint, I am trying to be able to click anywhere in the group by header element and have the group expand/collapse.  I have gotten it to work partially.  Right now I can click anywhere in the element except on the `<a>` tag that opens it.  How do I set the conditional to run the function when anywhere is clicked except the `<a>` tag?

Here is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var groupby = $(".ms-gb");
groupby.click(function(){
    var groupbyAnchor = $("a", this);
    groupbyAnchor = groupbyAnchor[0];
    expandThisGroup(groupbyAnchor)}); 
});

function expandThisGroup(anchor) {
anchor.click(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put another handler on the child element that prevents event propagation:

```
groupby.find("a").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might do it like this. Pass the `click` event target to the function, if the target is not the given `anchor`, do something, else do nothing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var groupby = $(".ms-gb");

    groupby.on('click', function(e){

        var $target = e.target,
            $anchor = $('a', this);

        if(!($target == $anchor)){
            // do function
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```